# how can i display first image which is an array in network image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a shop app in flutter where there will list of the product images in the product detail page I want to display the first product image on the product page from an array, How can I pick the first image from an array and display it in network image!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the first position of an array. Like:

`images[0]` since arrays starts from 0.